# Tabela não Carregando

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel

Estou tentando fazer a lista da tabela carregar e não carregar sempre dá esse erro

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor PanelListClientes() is undefined

at view.FramePrincipal.listClientClicked(FramePrincipal.java:118)
at view.FramePrincipal$6.actionPerformed(FramePrincipal.java:94)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

O meu Código da view é esse

```
public class PanelListClientes extends JPanel {
private JTable table;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */

public PanelListClientes(TableCliente tablecliente) {
    setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 181, 430, 108);
    add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(tablecliente);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    JButton btnCarregarTabela = new JButton("Carregar Tabela");
    btnCarregarTabela.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CarregarClicked(e);
        }
    });
    btnCarregarTabela.setBounds(267, 135, 142, 23);
    add(btnCarregarTabela);

}

protected void CarregarClicked(ActionEvent e) {
    ControleCliente cCliente = new ControleCliente();
    cCliente.constroiTabela();

}
```

O metodo que dá erro é esse do menu principal

```
protected void listClientClicked(ActionEvent e) {
    PanelListClientes plClientes = new PanelListClientes();
    this.setContentPane(plClientes);

}
```

[image: É um menu JFrame chamando a JPanel para depois carregar a tabela]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está bem claro. Nesta linha:

```
PanelListClientes plClientes = new PanelListClientes();
```

você está tentando iniciar a classe com um construtor sem parâmetros, mas na sua classe `PanelListClientes` há um construtor que espera um tipo `TableCliente` como parâmetro.

Em java, quando você não escrever um construtor para uma classe, é criado um construtor padrão sem parâmetros que você não vê, mas ele está lá quando a classe é instanciada. A partir do momento que você define um construtor, seja com parâmetros ou não, o compilador entender que você está assumindo a responsabilidade da inicialização da classe e não cria nada.

Para resolver, você deve respeitar o construtor que você mesmo criou, e passar o parâmetro esperado, ou criar uma inicialização alternativa da sua classe com um construtor sem parâmetro.

Comment: Ah sim entendi, perfeito mais
Como eu poderia criar esse inicialização qual alternativa porque ele não consegue criar a table.

Comment: @DiegoCruz acho que está havendo o erro de entendimento seu do seu proprio codigo. Se você quer iniciar sem passar a tabela, pra que criou construtor recebendo uma?